# Polymer Elements trigger update

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

If I have two completely different polymer elements, and in one i have

```html
<template if="{{MyVar}}">htmlhere</template> 
<template if="{{!MyVar}}">otherhtmlhere</template>
```

the other i have

```html
<template if="{{MyVar}}">hello</template> 
<template if="{{!MyVar}}">world</template>
```

what I want to do is if on one `MyVar` changes, it should change on the other as well... How would I handle this situation?

To explain further what I am looking for is in effect a way to have various bindings / reactions throughout the whole page... so if some method / module somewhere changes MyVar's state it would ripple through the entire page make changes where it should

Comment: If MyVar in both places refers to the same instance, and it is properly observable, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I have an observable object in the root polymer element which I assign to an attribute of the child polymer element.

The child polymer element can then bind to this attribute.

**AppModel (global model)**

```dart
class AppModel extends Object with Observable {
  @observable bool isLoggedIn = false;
  @observable List<String> authenticationProvider = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'GitHub', 'Amazon'];
}


@CustomTag("app-element")
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable AppModel appModel;

  AppElement.created() : super.created() {
  }
}
```

**AppElement (html)** here the global model get's assigned to a child element

```html
<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <my-login id="mylogin" model="{{appModel}}"></my-login>
  </template>
  ...
</polymer-element>
```

**MyLogin (dart)** the model Attribute is assigned to the model field.

```dart
@CustomTag("my-login")
class MyLogin extends PolymerElement {

  MyLogin.created() : super.created();

  @published AppModel model;
}
```

**MyLogin (html)** the global model is used to show/hide the login button/logged-in user info

```html
<polymer-element name="bwu-login"> 
  <template>
    <template if="{{!model.isLoggedIn}}">
      <bs-dropdown>
        <div class="dropdown">

          <div class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default btn-xs navbar-btn" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login
          </div>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="select authentication provider">
            <template repeat="{{ap in model.authenticationProvider}}">
              <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ap.authenticationUrl}}" on-click="{{openLogin}}" target="_blank">{{ap.name}}</a>

               </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </bs-dropdown>
    </template>

    <template if="{{model.isLoggedIn}}">
      <small>{{model.name}}<template if="{{model.isAdmin}}">&nbsp;(Admin)</template></small>
      <div id="logoutButton" on-click="{{onLogoutHandler}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs navbar-btn" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Logout
      </div>

      <!--<div><img src="{{model.avatar}}"></img>{{model.name}} <button id="logout">Log out</button></div>-->
    </template>

  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src='my_login.dart'></script>

</polymer-element>
```